Bitcoins Day Destroyed - 9K Views
I noticed that the What are “bitcoin days destroyed”? question has 9K views. It is indeed a good question, but why is the view count so high? Is it a bug? Most questions, even the highest voted ones, are around 300 views.

It isn't a bug.
The question was posted on Hacker News which has brought in the majority of traffic on that question.
